# how to create below folder structure using python or shell?

Tags: python, shell

[image]

This is sample structure of my file system, I have folder names in .text file and I Call This File In My Shell-script or python how can I create this file structure recursively and I need only folder names in below structure?

```
d-r-x   - moka.babu HDFS   0 2018-08-23 12:58 /HCDLPRD/user
d-r-x   - moka.babu HDFS   0 2018-08-23 12:58 /hcdlprd/user/moka.babu
d-r-x  -  moka.babu HDFS   0 2018-08-23 12:58 /hcdlprd/user/moka.babu/hive
```

Comment: How does that .txt file look explicitly?

Comment: my lines like this in 20k above

Comment: @C.Nivs yeah posted pic ,just check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Python

OP has stated that `ls -ltr` was explicitly copied into a file. We can clean it with `awk` first to get just the files into the file

```
awk -F '[[:space:]]+' 'NR > 1 {print $9}' file >> cleaned.txt
```

This will split each row into pieces per multiple spaces and send the filename (in column 9) to the file, yielding the following:

```
/ranger/audit/atlas/20180629
/ranger/audit/atlas/20180630
```

In python:

```
import os
# open the file to be read
with open('cleaned.txt') as fh:

    for dir in fh:
        try:
            os.mkdir(dir)
            # If you don't want root write access
            os.chmod(dir, 555)
        # In case the root directory already exists
        except FileExistsError as e:
            print(e)
            continue
```

### In bash

Check @hansolo's answer, as this will be effectively the same

### EDIT: In case one folder in a directory *might not* exist

In the case where you have a folder:
    /hcdlprd/user/head/some/dir/file.txt

Where `head` was not created by the script *before* this line, you can create a more robust solution:

```
try:
    os.mkdir(dir)
except FileExistsError as e:
    print(e)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    sub_dir, i = "", 1

    # filenotfound will show that some component of the path doesn't exist
    # so we will check the sub-directories for existence and
    # make them if they are empty
    while sub_dir!=dir:
        # grab a sub-directory ('/path/to/subdir')
        sub_dir = os.path.join(os.path.split(dir)[:i])
        # check if it's not a directory, if not make it
        # if it is, continue on
        if not os.path.isdir(sub_dir):
            os.mkdir(sub_dir)
        i+=1
```

In case `awk` is a bit weird to conceptualize, we can wrap everything in python by processing each line with the following:

```
def process_lines(fh):
    for line in fh:
        split_out = line.split() # split on spaces, creating a list
        path = split_out[-1] # the file is the last entry
        yield path

with open('cleaned.txt') as fh:
    for dir in process_lines(fh):
        # rest of code at top
```

Comment: @ d-r-x   - moka.babu HDFS   0 2018-08-23 12:58 /HCDLPRD/user                           my folder structure like this i need only last parameter

Comment: oh so you've explicitly recorded `ls -ltr` into a file

Comment: Ok, my edit at the start should help get the file into a nicer format

Comment: thanks @C.Nivs this folder structure in cluster environment ,i replicate this same another cluster ,so i tried to find the all files using hdfs dfs -ls -R /prod | grep "^d" >> /tmp/a.txt ,this a.txt file is above one. now i need only foldernames in that file.i dnt need the all parameters.

Comment: the `awk` command should do that

Comment: I've added a python implementation of what `awk` is doing at the bottom of my answer

Comment: in hadoop file system awk is not work?

Comment: So the question should be titled *How to Create folders in HDFS* not *How to Create folders in python/shell*, and tagged accordingly

Comment: thanks for the help, i needed in python or shell only because i need to execute this files in linux env

Comment: You could pipe `ls -ltr` from `hdfs dfs` to `awk` like the following:
`hdfs dfs -ls -R /prod | awk -F '[[:space:]]+' 'NR > 1 {print $9}' >> somefile.txt`. However, it's considered bad practice to pipe `ls`

Answer (score 0):

you can read the lines in, split each line at the space with `.split(' ')` and then index the last value to get folder name. Then just `import os` followed with `for folder in folders:` `os.mkdir(folder)`

Here is an example with basic error checking that will print what file could not be created:

```
import os

with open('files.txt', 'r') as file:
    file_list = file.readlines()

for file in file_list:
    filename = file.split(' ')[-1].rstrip()[1:]
    try:
        os.mkdir(filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

In any shell:

```
mkdir -p /hcdlprd/user/moka.babu/hive
```

The command will create the entire structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ cat file
d-r-x   - moka.babu HDFS   0 2018-08-23 12:58 /HCDLPRD/user
d-r-x   - moka.babu HDFS   0 2018-08-23 12:58 /hcdlprd/user/moka.babu
d-r-x  -  moka.babu HDFS   0 2018-08-23 12:58 /hcdlprd/user/moka.babu/hive

$ awk '{ system("mkdir -p " $NF); }' file
```

You can see the structures created.

Comment: i have 26,000 lines like this structure

Comment: All those are directories ?

Comment: they are output from `ls -ltr` which contains a ton of unnecessary information. Yours works perfectly well if the file only contains paths, which it does not. Not a knock against your answer, as you posted before OP clarified the contents of the file

Comment: I wasn't sure if the content of the file has the `ls` output or only the paths. And parsing the output of `ls` is crazy. I'd have used `find` to get the structure instead.